# Resources on Data Science for Football / Soccer in-line?

Tags: data-request, sports, historical

Similar question was already asked in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/resources-on-data-science-for-football-soccer, but I am looking for historical data of off-line + in-line matches.

I know few portals that provides coefficients during the game:

- http://www.oddsportal.com/
- http://www.betbrain.com

However, I would be very appreciated for advise where I can find resources with already saved in-line historical data for soccer matches.

Answer (score 3):

This one wasn't mentioned yet: Human-readable: [openfootball](http://openfootball.github.io/) , its data is here: [football.db](https://github.com/openfootball).

[Search on github.com](https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=football+site%3Agithub.com) for more repositories with football data.